# Dateformat sometimes yyyy-mm-dd wrong ms-sql 2012

Tags: sql-server, date

i have a database table with a datetime column.
I use the management studio on the server to directly enter SQL commands. This happens:
(Note the date time yyyy-mm-dd format)

```
DECLARE @DATETIME DATETIME= '1912-05-20'  <- WORKING (expected)
DECLARE @DATETIME DATETIME= '1912-20-05'  <- Not WORKING  (expected)
SELECT * FROM dbo.Messwerte WHERE 'dbo.Messwerte.datetime' = '2021-17-05'   <--  Working  (not expected)
SELECT * FROM dbo.Messwerte WHERE 'dbo.Messwerte.datetime' = '2021-05-17'   <--  Not Working (not expected)
Select * From dbo.Messwerte where DateTime between '2021/10/28' and '2021/10/29' <--  Not Working (not expected)
Select * From dbo.Messwerte where DateTime between '2021/28/10' and '2021/29/10' <-- Working (not expected)
```

This problem is only on my server. The yyyy-mm-dd format is sometimes rotated interpretet.

German Windows 10 Pro
MS SQL Server 2018

What setting is wrong?

Comment: Select * From dbo.Messwerte where 'dbo.Messwerte.DateTime' > '20212810T00:00:00.000' is working. Why?

Comment: Select * From dbo.Messwerte where DateTime > '20212810' is working (not sure) but Select * From dbo.Messwerte where DateTime > '20222810' not. He is interpreting the year strange

Comment: Select * From dbo.Messwerte where [DateTime] > '20211018T00:00:00.000' is not working and give error can not convert to time.

Comment: Ok. Working now (: Thank you very mutch

Comment: I see `1912-20-05` and I'm left wondering what you expected to get for the 20th **MONTH** of 1912. Regardless of what the language or cultural norms are for where you live, SQL is its own language that **always** expects year, then month, then day. Otherwise, how would it know what to do for dates like `19120203`, which could go both ways?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your date format needs to be one of these:

```
YYYYMMDD
YYYYMMDD HH:MM:SS.nnn
YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS.nnn
```

These will NOT work (either ever, or reliably across different languages):

```
YYYY-MM-DD
YYYY-DD-MM
YYYY/MM/DD
YYYY/DD/MM  
YYYYMMDDTHH:MM:SS.nnn
```

So your query needs to be either:

```
... WHERE [DateTime] > '2021-10-18T00:00:00.000';
```

Or

```
... WHERE [DateTime] > '20211018';
```

Please read some of the links at [Dating Responsibly](https://sqlblog.org/dates).